# How to generate effects similar to this in libgdx for android games?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

from here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cuDdUEQdYz4

this colored effect when the character hits the bad guys

[image]

of course the character can be show by sprites, but how to do such visual effects ?

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by playing still frames one by one manually. [SpriteAnimation](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SpriteAnimation) works very well for doing this as it removes some of the menial work.